# Do ManipulationDelta Events only work for Touch Inputs?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I thought that ManipulationDelta handled any kind of manipulation but I can't seem to get anything at all to work in WPF.  Are the manipulation events for touch only or does it work with the mouse as well?

It never hits my breakpoint the Starting event.
For example:

```
<Button Name="Test1" Width="75" Click="State1Button_Click" Content="Test"  ManipulationDelta="Expander_ManipulationDelta" ManipulationStarting="Expander_ManipulationStarting" IsManipulationEnabled="True">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform />
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        </Button>

private void Expander_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ManipulationContainer = TheParent;
        e.Mode = ManipulationModes.All; 
    }

    private void Expander_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        TranslateTransform tt = (sender as UIElement).RenderTransform as TranslateTransform;
        tt.X = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
        tt.Y = e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `ManipulationDelta` (and other manipulation events) result from touch events only.

From MSDN, [Input Overview - Touch and Manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx#touch_and_manipulation), section *The Relationship Between Touch and Manipulation Events*:

> A UIElement can always receive touch events. When the
>   IsManipulationEnabled property is set to true, a UIElement can receive
>   both touch and manipulation events. If the TouchDown event is not
>   handled (that is, the Handled property is false), the manipulation
>   logic captures the touch to the element and generates the manipulation
>   events. If the Handled property is set to true in the TouchDown event,
>   the manipulation logic does not generate manipulation events. The
>   following illustration shows the relationship between touch events and
>   manipulation events.
>
> Touch and manipulation events

[image]

Comment: Bummer, then it is as I feared.  I'll have to try and use the drag and drop events instead I guess.  Thank you.